# join tables on two different columns

Tags: mysql, join

```
Table 1   Bus_ID   Owner_ID   #owners in Bus
           12345       5558        3
           12345       5856        3
           52858     **7894**      1
           12345       1254        3

Table 2   Owner_1   Owner_2    Relationship
           5558      5856    Parent of Owner_1
           5558      1254    Parent of Owner_1
           1254      5856    Spouse
           5856      1254    Spouse
           **7894**  6868    Spouse
           6868    **7894**  Spouse
```

I have two table I want to join with eachother. It is only possible to join on the `Owner_ID = Owner_1` or `Owner_ID = Owner_2`. I want to eventually get the `Owner_ID` that are in table 1 aswel.

My expected results:

```
Bus_ID  Owner_ID  Owner_1  Owner_2  Relationship 
 12345    5558     5558     5856   Parent of Owner_1
 12345    5558     5558     1254   Parent of Owner_1
 12345    5856     5856     1254   Spouse
 12345    1254     1254     5856   Spouse
```

As you see if the Owner_ID does not appear in table 1 I don't want it to appear in the joint table, but when joining **7894** as there is a relationship in table 2 it will apear anyway the way I am joining them. I need help with the joining of these two table.

```
select Bus_ID, Owner_ID, Owner_1, Owner_2, Relationship from table 1 
join table 2 on (Owner_ID = Owner_1 AND Owner_ID = Owner_2).
```

This query wont give the output I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using join with multiple instance of table2 by alias

```
select Bus_ID, Owner_ID, t2.Owner_1, t3.Owner_2, t2.Relationship 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.Owner_ID = t2.Owner_1 
join table2 t3 on t1.Owner_ID = t3.Owner_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somehting like this :

```
select 
    Bus_ID, Owner_ID, Owner_1, Owner_2, Relationship 
from table 1 
inner join table 2 on Owner_ID = Owner_1

UNION

select 
    Bus_ID, Owner_ID, Owner_1, Owner_2, Relationship 
from table 1 
inner join table 2 on Owner_ID = Owner_2
```

This way you will get :

- All rows that respect the condition `Owner_ID = Owner_1`
- All rows that respect the condition `Owner_ID = Owner_2`

and you will return all of them at once.